# Android gridView for tic-tac-toe

Tags: android, gridview

HI,

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game as a learning exercise in Android app making.

To learn to use gridView, I have used it to set out a 3 x 3 game board (filled in with imageViews).  I have created a custom adapter which correctly loads the imageViews into the gridView, but I do not know how to make sure each cell's width shrinks small enough to just fit the image (so it looks like a 3 x 3 grid where all the cells are squares).

Can anyone help me out with this?

Here's my XML for the gridView:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to specify how the ImageViews are to be drawn when you create them in the adapter.

If you see the example at  [the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) they specify how the images are to be scaled:

```
 ImageView imageView;
 ...
 imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

There are different scaling options, including 'none' which might be suitable. There is also the possibility of changing how they are rendered with the

```
  imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

attribute, but how these different configurations interact is still fairly trial and error for me. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :).The ImageViews are already scaled properly, however the cells in the GridView are not square.  Or did you mean to increase the size of the ImageViews with trial and error until they line up properly?

Comment: I would suggest to make you layout match_parent in width, on runtime calculate the width, and divide by 3 and make each image view width and height. I think will make it square