# How to give animation in memory game in android?

Tags: android

I want to develop a memory game; there will be 4x5 images in a grid.  Let me show you an image.

[image]

But I need little bit animation. here I found a tutorial http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html. I want this type animation.

But somehow I can't get how I can make it in a GridView.

Any kind of help are appreciated.

Comment: Might want to look into Arrays. Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361216/android-gridview-for-tic-tac-toe for some GridView.

Comment: What have you got so far?  What's stumping you?  Is there a more specific question you can ask rather than "how do I make a kind of game?"

Comment: Actually Im stuck, how can I can manage all the FrameLayout in a grid. I need that animation. Thanks. @nil

Comment: What do you mean by "manage all the FrameLayout in a grid?"  How are you stuck?  What's stopping you from doing whatever it is you're trying to do?  And what are you trying to do, anyway?

Comment: I couldn't manage all the frame layout in a grid view. May be lake of knowledge. can you please help me on this, I just mention a link, I need all the image in a gridview and all image will behave use the same animation as the link showed. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @rokonoid - did my answer help at all? Do you need more information/help? Typically, one responds to people who take time to try and help them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `GridView`, the clicked View is provided in the `onItemClick()` callback.

Eg:

```
// mGridView is your GridView 
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {  
        // The View clicked on is v. Here you can call v.startAnimation();
    }
});
```

In order to achieve the `Flip3dAnimation`, linked to in your question, you must first implement the `FrameLayout`, described there, as your `GridView` items.